# Method in http-proxy-middleware does not work, how to fix it?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

From one service I send a request to an address for example http://gateway:3000/users, proxied using the http-proxy-middleware library to http://webamqplib:5557/. Works if I use the function
**reverse-proxy-middlewareBuilder.ts**

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { createProxyMiddleware, Filter, Options, RequestHandler } from 'http-proxy-middleware';
import { MiddlewareBuilder } from '@nestjs/core';

export function ReverseProxyMiddleware(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
   const proxy = createProxyMiddleware(req.path, {
   target: 'http://webamqplib:5557/',
   changeOrigin: true,
})
   proxy(req, res, next)
}
```

все хорошо отрабатывает, в консоле этого сервиса [HPM] Proxy created: /users -> webamqplib:5557

**Module -> users.module.ts**

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware, Scope } from '@nestjs/common';
import { createProxyMiddleware, Filter, Options, RequestHandler } from 'http-proxy-middleware';
import configs from './config/config.json';

@Injectable()
export class ReverseProxyMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  private proxy(path: Filter | Options, option?: Options): RequestHandler {

    return createProxyMiddleware(path, option)
}

use(req: Request, res: Response, next: () => void) {
  this.proxy(
     req.path, 
    {
      target: configs.users.target,
      changeOrigin: true
    }
  )
  next()
}
```

**Using a class** reverse-proxy-middlewareBuilder.ts

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { createProxyMiddleware, Filter, Options, RequestHandler } from 'http-proxy-middleware';
import configs from './config/config.json';

@Injectable()
export class ReverseProxyMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  private proxy(path: Filter | Options, option?: Options): RequestHandler {
    return createProxyMiddleware(path, option)
  }

  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: () => void) {
    this.proxy(
    req.path, 
    {
      target: configs.users.target,
      changeOrigin: true
    }
  )
 next()
}
}
```

When requesting http://gateway:3000/users, the console still displays [HPM] Proxy created: /users -> webamqplib:5557, as with the function, but the redirect does not occur to the address as in the first example

translated with the help of google translator :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you create a middleware for each request, instead of connecting it once, after which it will catch the requests.

In your case, you have to do this in `main.ts` file:

```js
  // main.ts
  import { createProxyMiddleware } from 'http-proxy-middleware';
  ...
  app.use("*", createProxyMiddleware({
    target: 'http://webamqplib:5557',
    changeOrigin: true,
  }));
```

That's how it works for me.